# Couldn't display more than one data on each tab: TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbarcontroller

I am new in a flutter, now when I am trying to display multiple cards inside a ListView on each tab in TabBarView I get this error

**" Controller's length property (4) does not match the number of tabs (5) present in TabBar's tabs property. "**

and here is my code, is there a way to do this?

this is the TabBar

```
child: TabBar(
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(child: Text("New", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),),
                          Tab(child: Text("Indoor", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),),
                          Tab(child: Text("Outdoor", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),),
                          Tab(child: Text("Furniture", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),),
                        ],
                      indicatorColor: Color.fromRGBO(230, 0, 49, 0.86),
                    ),
```

and this is the TabBarView

```
child: TabBarView(
                      children:
                    [
                      //First tab

                      ListView(
                        children: [
                          Card(
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                            elevation: 0.5,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),

                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 0.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {

                                },
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                                        child: Ink.image(
                                            height: 200,
                                            image: AssetImage('assets/images/kitchen.jpg'),
                                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                                      ),
                                    ]),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text(
                                        "Project Name",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      subtitle: Text(
                                        "Project details descriptions",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            color: Colors.grey),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),


                    ListView(
                        children: [
                      Card(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        elevation: 0.5,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),

                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 0.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {

                            },
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                                    child: Ink.image(
                                        height: 200,
                                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/food_tables.jpg'),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                                ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    "Project Name",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    "Project details descriptions",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        color: Colors.grey),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                        ],
                      ),
                     ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 tabs but you have 2 listview in tabbarViews.

For solution you have to remove 2 tabs or you can add 2 more widget in tabbarview

```
TabBarView(children: [
    // 1.tab
    Container(),
    // 2.tab
    Container(),
    // 3.tab
    Container(),
    // 4.tab
    Container(),
  ]);
```